# Any way to insert a pop-up text box in a PDF fillable form?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have created a fillable form in PDF, using Acrobat XI. I did a small experience check to see how the intended users were using it. Well mostly, people started printing it and writing on it.

There is an information bar that appears on top of the PDF, which says the form is fillable, but I feel it falls on the blind spot on the users.

Is it possible to put up a pop-up box, where it says that you can type data into the form etc, and the user has to click ok to get past it? Is such a feature available with Acrobat XI Pro. I Googled, but not much help

Comment: "Never underestimate the power of human stupidity"  ;) +1 for the question, though idk the answer, sorry.

Comment: Do you mean like this http://www.pdfshareforms.com/how-to-create-nice-dialog-windows-in-pdf-form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do it, if you are OK with a simple message would be creating a document-level JavaScript with the following code:

```
app.alert("This form is fillable") ;
```

If you want some eye candy, a still simple way would be to create the message in the layout program, save it as PDF, and then add a button field (read-only, no action) and make that PDF the icon of that button. Then you add another button, labelled OK.

The action of the OK button is to hide the message button and the OK button itself, and then set the focus to the first field (which would best be covered by the message button field. The JavaScript code for the MouseUp event of the OK button would then read:

```
this.getField("theMessage").display = display.hidden ;
event.target.display = display.hidden ;
this.getField("theFirstEntryField").setFocus() ;
```

You would save the form with the message button and the OK button being visible. If you want to show the buttons every time the document opens, even after it has been saved by the user, you would create a document-level script:

```
this.getField("theMessage").display = display.visible ;
this.getField("theOKBox").display = display.visible ;
```

and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks. I Liked the first step, only if it could change the Cross ICON to an Exclamation or a Tick icon. The other instructions are complicated for me to follow.

Comment: ok, got a hang of it.. got more options from here https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/popup_windows_part1

Comment: There is the "status" icon, which you activate with app.alert("This form is fillable.", 3) ;

Comment: The Title of the box contains a persistent message "Warning: Javascript Console".. Any way to get that removed?

Comment: @Firee: Are you sure that it says "Warning: JavaScript Console"? And, no, this warning can not be suppressed; Adobe considers it to be a security feature.

Comment: Sorry, it says "Warning: JavaScript Window"

Comment: I thought so… As said, this warning can not be suppressed, despite its high annoyance level and over-use. We all have to live with that.

Comment: I think I can live with that, many thanks once again